# Galaxy s4 mini (GT I9192) - Android 4.4.2 .... Storage space depleting even though data being deleted

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, insufficient-memory, storage, system-freeze, samsung-galaxy-s-4-mini

So this is a recent development since last night.. when the phone suddenly started misbehaving. Hanging, apps crashing, working really slow, screen going blank, <kbd>Vol</kbd> / <kbd>Power key</kbd>  buttons not working etc.

Messages kept popping up that storage space is low.. with great difficulty managed to delete apps and other data. Images, audio, video etc. The instant I clear up and check storage it will indicate the appropriate amount - 200 mb, 300 mb...

However in a few seconds, the same issues of hanging reoccur, and upon checking storage I see that it has gone back down to 180 mb, 700 kb n finally now its showing 56 kb despite having removed more than 2 gb worth of data and apps. CACHE continually being deleted, best I can do since the phone is barely functioning, but it keeps filling up to about 1.84 mb (not that it matters).

Help! I cannot purchase a new phone as I do NOT have the funds for it.
I also get a pop up which goes something like `android.acore` stopped functioning. Sometimes `"process system" stopped functioning` along  with the usual pop ups of Whatsapp, Google apps, Touchwiz not functioning.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all your (CM) protection apps, thread and cache cleaners, battery savers and so one. Do not use frabrique reset or cache cleaning. It do nothing then erares all your address and other personal data and it's not the cause. The cause is that some protection apps are the treats. I've removed all mine (CM ) protecting apps and there is no stoped message any more. I use Sophos for this moment as protection app there it now the best in the AVG test.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the option to see hidden files from my files. Then, go to my files and check what are the large files causing this issue.

Also, another temporary solution is to delete the thumbnails folder from DCIM (camera folder). It is about 300 or 400 MB usually. If you had enough space to install a small app, then Go install ES Disk Analyzer: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.storage.space.es.diskanalyzer

It is high quality application that helps you address these issues.